# Read piped input from other script, while also reading user input, in Python (2.7 and 3.x)

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-2.7, console

I have two Python scripts where I want to pipe the output from the first script, into the second script, while also being able to read user input from console in the second script.

This is very simplified example code, to give an idea of what I'm trying to do:

py_a.py

```
print(1+2)
```

py_b.py

```
import sys

invalue = sys.stdin.read()
print("value from py_a is " + invalue)

answer = input("Talk to me! ")
# do something with answer
```

And in terminal I wish to do something like
`python py_a.py | python py_b.py`

However, when I try to get input from console, the following happen:

```
Talk to me! Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "py_b.py", line 3, in <module>
    answer = input("Talk to me! ")
EOFError: EOF when reading a line
```

Any ideas on how I can get this to work?

Answer (score 0):

You've already exhausted the standard input and reached its end-of-file by using the `read()` method, which reads the entire file stream until the EOF, so when `input()` wants to read more from the same file stream, it can't because the file stream has already reached EOF.

You should remove the line `line = sys.stdin.read()` since you really just want one line of input from the user, which the `input()` function will do.

**EDIT:** If you want `py_b.py` to be able to read from the console after reading standard input piped from `py_a.py`, you can install the [`keyboard`](https://pypi.org/project/keyboard/) module to read directly from the user's keyboard instead:

```
import keyboard
import time

class InputHandler:
    def __init__(self):
        self.buffer = ''

    def on_press(self, event):
        if event.name == 'enter':
            self.do_something()
            self.buffer = ''
        elif event.name == 'backspace':
            self.buffer = self.buffer[:-1]
        else:
            self.buffer += event.name

    def do_something(self):
        global running
        if self.buffer == 'exit':
            running = False
        print('You entered: ' + self.buffer)

invalue = sys.stdin.read()
print("value from py_a is " + invalue)

keyboard.on_press(InputHandler().on_press)
running = True
while running:
    time.sleep(1)
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer! However, I realise that in my example code it is not obvious that I actually wish to use the value that is piped from the first script, so it is not enough to just remove reading from stdin at that point. I'll edit my original post to reflect that.

Comment: That's not how standard input works. Standard input can only come from one source. So if you choose to pipe the output of `py_a.py` to `py_b.py`, then `py_b.py` will not be able to get the user's input from standard input.

Comment: That explains why it's hard to get it to work, then :). I'll just have to choose one of them. Thank you so much for your help! Even if I'm not able to do what I want, it saves me a lot of time to know it's just not possible.

Comment: I've updated my answer with how you can read from the console after reading standard input from a pipe.